# My code is bringing my fibonacci sequence out one number short (Python college course)

Tags: python

I have this program which is supposed to take the sum of all integers from 1 and including the input integer. Get the factorial of the input integer, and then take that integer to calculate the number in the fibonacci sequence. I believe I did all of this correctly except the fibonacci number is coming out 1 short.

```
# This program should find the factorial of the interger

#Used for later

# takes the user input
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
factorial = 1

# Gets the sum

sum_up_to_number = 0
tnum = 1
while tnum <= num:
 sum_up_to_number += tnum
 tnum += 1

print("Sum of all numbers up to", num, "is", sum_up_to_number )



#Gets the factorial

if num < 0:
 print("Sorry, factorial does not exist for negative numbers")
elif num == 0:
 print("The factorial of 0 is 1")
else:
 for i in range(1,num + 1):
   factorial = factorial*i
 print("The factorial of",num,"is",factorial)


# Should begin the process the making the getting the sum and the fibonacci

# Takes your num to start the fibonacci sequence
nterms = num

# first two terms
n1 = 0
n2 = 1
count = 2

# check if the number of terms is valid
fibonacci_sum = 0 #A small check to make sure it receives something it wants
if nterms <= 0:
 print("Plese enter a positive integer")
elif nterms == 1:    #A small check to make sure it receives something it wants
 print("Fibonacci sequence:")
 print(n1)
else:
 print("Fibonacci sequence:")   #Gives the sequence since it receives an input it likes
 print(n1,",",n2,end=', ')
while count < nterms: #Retrieves the fibonacci sequence

   nth = n1 + n2
   print(nth,end=' , ')
   # update values
   n1 = n2
   n2 = nth
   count += 1
print("") #Makes the sequence of the print clean
print(num, "number of Fibonacci sequence is", n2) #Gives the original integer and then the final number in the fibonacci sequence
```

I need to figure out how to not make the fibonacci come out one number short.

Comment: what about `while count <= nterms:`?

Comment: Set `n1 = 1` instead of 0.

Comment: @Rawing Completely overlooked it. Thanks for the fix my man.